# Create SharePoint online Site Templates using Logic App Vs using Power Automate

Tags: office-365, power-automate, azure, site-script, logic-app

In our Office 365 tenant, we currently do not have any custom Site Templates, as follow:-

[image]

and we want to start developing such Site Templates, and based on my reading seems there are 2 ways to do so:-

1. Logic App
2. Power Automate

now seems both provide the same capabilities, but to use Power Automate we need to have premium license since we need to have HTTP trigger connector. so other than this point regarding the licenses what are the main differences between using logic App and using Power Automate to create site temapltes?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Logic Apps underly Power Automate, though are missing certain connectors -- in this use-case, everything you need is available in Logic Apps. I prefer using Logic Apps as they're not "tied" to a single user.

While now out of date due to using an old PnP module, I provided a write-up [here](https://thesharepointfarm.com/2020/12/sharepoint-azure-pnp-provisioning/). The fundamental concepts are still the same, but the authentication of the new PnP.PowerShell module has changed.